# On Gitbash - Bower : ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH

Tags: node.js, git, bower

I have a project with bower.json file and im trying to load all it's bower libraries on Windows.
I turn on Gitbash, cd to that project directory and type in bower install / bower update.
I receive an error:

```
bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

But there is a path to git:

```
$ which git
/bin/git
```

So the wierd thing that it actually works in cmd on Windows, **but it doesnt work with Gitbash**.
This is the value i have in the system PATH env variable regarding git:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Develop\VCS\Git\cmd
```

I tried to re-install msysgit and chose the option: Run Git From Windows Command Prompt like so:

[image]

It still doesnt seem to work..

Bower version:

```
$ bower --version
1.4.1
```

Git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

- Bower is installed globally using npm

EDIT:
I found the cause of this issue:
I have a file in my profile home directory .bashrc that i usually use in order to define general aliases and so on and i added this line:

```
export PATH="~/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin":$PATH
```

And somehow when this line is present i receive the error in Gitbash, wierd though, it just add the path to global composer packages, what it has to do with git itself or bower?

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution posted by [saurabhkohli](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/972#issuecomment-32154604) in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/972):

> [U]pdating the PATH environment variable with the current installed location of the GIT in your system will help resolve this issue, or you can update the same in your NodeJS command prompt by using `"set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;"`

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same issue when trying to use windows command line.
Turns out, you have to select this setting twice and I have missed the second one.

Here's a few screenshots if any help for anyone:

[image: i]

The one I have missed:
[image: j]

After reinstalling with the above settings, everything seem to be ok.

Comment: I could even be better if you write the plain text associated with the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unzip a portable Git in a simpler path (no space).
Take the latest one from git for Windows: [`PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.5.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe).
(no setup required, just an auto-extractable archive here)

Remove from your `PATH` the old msysgit, and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\bin` to the `%PATH%`.

Comment: Hey VonC thanks for you answer but check out my new Edit for this question, i found the issue but didnt understand why its problematic.

Comment: @Lihai I would be curious to see if that line would work, when used with the more recent Git I mention in the answer, with a simpler PATH.

Comment: Even when i add only this line to .bashrc file it shows the error: export PATH="~/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin":$PATH , and its composer for php libraries lol, i think whenever you try to edit the path using .bashrc file something fcked up and bower cant find the real path to git, dont know why.... so dont use export PATH in windows.

Comment: @Lihai you could echo the PATH in that same .bashrc, just to see how it looks: that could explain why git is no longer accessible.

Comment: can you try it also and tell me if u got the same issue? just create .bashrc and add: export PATH=whatever/path:$PATH

Comment: and btw i echo $PATH when i have the error and when i dont have the erorr, the only difference is that $PATH contain "~/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin" when there is an error.

Comment: @Lihai could you try and replace ~by $HOME (or check if $HOME is well defined)?