# Why can't I install googleapis?

Tags: node.js, git, npm-install

I try to install googleapis via `npm install googleapis`, but something goes wrong.

The error stack:

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:73:28)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:76:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:84:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/rynomad/jsbn.git resetting remote
C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-ryn
omad-jsbn-git-fe54fe73 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT
' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi
t-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/rynomad/jsbn.git C:\Users\Valen
tine11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-rynomad-jsbn-git-
fe54fe73: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Valentine11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_gi
t-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/rynomad/jsbn.git C:\Users\Valen
tine11\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-rynomad-jsbn-git-
fe54fe73: undefined
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing ecc-jsbn@0.0.1
googleapis@5.2.1 node_modules\googleapis
├── async@1.5.2
├── string-template@1.0.0
├── url@0.11.0 (punycode@1.3.2, querystring@0.2.0)
├── gapitoken@0.1.5 (jws@3.0.0)
├── request@2.72.0 (aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.2, oa
uth-sign@0.8.1, is-typedarray@1.0.0, caseless@0.11.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstre
am@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, form-data@1.0.0-rc4, tough-co
okie@2.2.2, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@6.1.0, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.10,
 aws4@1.3.2, hawk@3.1.3, bl@1.1.2, http-signature@1.1.1, har-validator@2.0.6)
└── google-auth-library@0.9.7 (lodash.noop@3.0.1, async@1.4.2, string-template@0
.2.1, jws@3.0.0, request@2.60.0, gtoken@1.2.0)
```

I already installed some packages and all is right. What am i doing wrong?
I have Git (and Git Extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the Git binaries on the PATH in the environment you are executing the npm command in (console, bash, etc.). You will find answers in this post: [On Gitbash - Bower : ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488176/on-gitbash-bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path)